# ¿Como guardar crear un mkdir con el nombre que se a ingresado mediante read en bash?

Tags: bash

E intentado de varias formas, pero no logro dar con lo que quiero realizar, el codigo que e intentado es el siguiente:

```
echo "introducir nombre de carpeta a crear: "
read $nombre
mkdir $nombre
```

---

Sigo teniendo el mismo problema!, y en vez de guardarse el nombre ingresado se guarda el mkdir como $directory_name

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Por favor indica cómo lo estás ejecutando? Usas WSL en Windows? Todo lo que debas añadir para explicar qué pasa o responder preguntas, añádelo usando la opción de [edit]

Comment: La solución que ofreció @an-tet me funciono correctamente, copie y pegue los 3 comandos en la consola directamente seguido de ENTER y escribí el nombre del directorio (se creo sin el $). Lo hice desde terminal de WSL

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux entonces marcarla como aceptada, por favor. A ver si a este comentario sí le haces caso

Comment: @Alfabravo la marque como aceptada de inmediato a penas me funciono.

Comment: Nop. Una cosa es votar positivo y otra hacer clic en el tick que está justo debajo de los votos de esa respuesta ;)

Comment: Le di a respuesta util, no puedo darle a respuesta aceptada el OP si puede, no me sale la palomita esa.

Answer (score 2):

El error esta en el **read** retira el signo **$** que esta antepuesto el nombre de la variable ya que no es necesario

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the directory name: "
read directory_name
mkdir $directory_name
```